# How to get back the passed parameter $state.transitionTo?

Tags: angularjs

i have a function called editDetails().. i am able navigate to viewproviderEdit.html page but how to receive parameter i passed in new controller

function

```
          $scope.editDetails = function() {
            console.log("id is ", id)
            $state.transitionTo('app.viewproviderEdit', {stateParamKey: id});
          }
```

app.router.js

```
                .state('app.viewproviderEdit', {
                    url: '/view-provider-edit/:id',
                    templateUrl: 'manage_provider/viewproviderEdit.html',
                    controller: 'viewprovidereditCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                            function($ocLazyLoad) {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load('xeditable').then(
                                    function() {
                                        return $ocLazyLoad.load('manage_provider/viewproviderEdit.js');
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                })
```

viewproviderEdit.js

```
  app.controller('viewprovidereditCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter','$state',
    function($scope, $filter,$state){
        if($state.current.name === 'app.viewproviderEdit')
        {
            console.log("coming inside new controller");
            // above console is working
        }
   }]);
```

How to get id in viewprovidereditCtrl controller. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $scope.editDetails = function() {
        console.log("id is ", id)
        $state.transitionTo('app.viewproviderEdit', {id:id});
      }
```

and change your controller

```
 app.controller('viewprovidereditCtrl', ['$scope','$filter','$state','$stateParams',
function($scope, $filter,$state,$stateParams){
    if($state.current.name === 'app.viewproviderEdit')
    {
        console.log("coming inside new controller");
        // above console is working
        console.log($stateParams.id);
    }
}]);
```

Use $stateParams for this :)

Comment: its giving 2 errors after injecting $stateParams  1)Unexpected token function (in line number 1)  2)Argument 'viewprovidereditCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: i included viewproviderEdit.js in index.html file then also am getting 'viewprovidereditCtrl' is not a function, got undefined'

Comment: Where am missing comma ujjwal

Comment: First line in controller before function($scope, $filter,$state,$stateParams)
not in your code , was silly mistake in my answer :(

Comment: yeah.. but 'console.log($stateParams.id);' is displaying undefined

Comment: What about console.log($state.params.id); ?

Comment: am getting it as blank

Comment: Your are sending id wrong , have changed the function code . Hope this helps . Let me know